# How can I fix this skybox seam(Unity)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, shader-graph

there!
I've used Unlit Shader Graph to make this skybox, and it looks mostly fine, but there is that annoying seam in the sky I don't know how to fix. Can anyone help?

*Sky box seam in scene view*[image: 1]

*The same seam, but with more stars*[image: 2]

*Skybox settings*[image: 3]
*Shader graph*[image: 4]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we followed the same Youtube tutorial cause I ended up with your exact same graph.

Anyway, I managed to fix the seam problem thanks to this blog post: https://jannikboysen.de/reaching-for-the-stars/

Just recreate the SkyboxUV subgraph explained in there and use that instead of the Position and Normalize nodes (so plug the SkyboxUV node output to the Tiling and Offset input).

This worked for me on Unity 2021.3.4f1.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it once I get home.